# Spring boot application startup stuck loading hibernate files

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using spring boot application with hibernate to connect to postgressql, but when I am running my application with run as spring boot app the starting of server is stuck  with loading hibernate files 
[image: application startup stuck loading hibernate files] without any error, I am stuck on this and it's not also showing any error.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: i am using maven

Comment: Try to use extended logging, for example "trace" mode of sl4j logger and find out why does it hangs up.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your app properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

or in your code the below

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There was another instance of Postgresql server was running and i was also not able to kiss the process that's why the application was stuck, i restarted my system and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA, check your repository configuration. Spring can spend a very long time scanning for JPA repositories if you don't have `basePackages` or `basePackageClasses` set in your `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation (this can be added by [JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.html) if your setup meets that class's `@ConditionalOn` requirements).